# Not asking camera and photo library permissions in ios 11

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4, ios11, ios-permissions

I am facing an issue in camera and photo library permission in iOS 11.0.
I have entered permissions in Info.plist given below :

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Hello</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

if I open image picker it is not asking for permissions but it is working in iOS 10.

I have checked lot of questions but didn't find any solution.
checked Questions given below :

- [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904468/privacy-issues-with-camera-and-photo-library-in-swift)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405881/ios-11-not-asking-permission-for-access-photo-from-the-app)
- [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759601/permission-is-not-working-prior-ios-10-in-swift)